# why the verb after 'be' must use past participle?

Tags: grammar

"She might be loved forever". I don't know why the 'loved' have to use in the past participle? Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: What else do you want to follow *be* with? It's *grammatical* to say *she might be love tomorrow*, but it doesn't make any sense. (Unless it's a fantasy novel where a woman can become the personification of Love, in which case it would have a capital letter.)

Comment: "Loved" is ambiguous here. It may be a past participle in a passive clause, or it could be an adjective with a stative meaning.